# obtain the line count of all files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have 3 files in directory "work" which will be pumped on daily basis.

files are as shown below:

```
ZNAMI DOWN COND RESULT_17-08-2015.csv
ZNAMI UP CND RESULT_18-08-2015.csv
ZNAMI DOWN COND RESULT_17-08-2015.csv
```

These files have many rows with just ",,,,,,,,," as input along with actual data.

What I need to perform is as below:

1. open each file [should be dynamic as everyday , date part changes].
2. Remove the lines with ",,,,,,,,,".
3. Get the line count.

I tried `wc -l *.csv` but it does not give the total count of all lines.
I also tried `sed -i ",,,,,,,,,"d *.csv` to remove the lines . But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
grep -v ",,,,,,,,," *.csv | wc -l
```

This will print every line from `*.csv` file that does *not* contain `,,,,,,,,,` to the standard output. Piping it into `wc` will yield total count of such lines.

Comment: No. It is giving count mismatch

Comment: If you need to do that for each file separately, just replace it with a loop: `for x in *.csv; do echo -n "$x: "; grep -v ",,,,,,,,,"  "$x" | wc -l; done`

Comment: It is giving count mismatch. Can we change this so that the pattern begins with ",,,,,,,,,"

Comment: "begin with ..":  Do you mean at the start of the line? That is possible with the special char `^`: `grep -v "^,,,,,,,,," *.csv | wc -l`. Otherwise try to explain/test which lines don't get counted or are counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '!/,,,,,,,,,/{n++;} END{print n;}' *.csv
```

This counts every line that does not contain `,,,,,,,,,`.

- `!/,,,,,,,,,/{n++;}`

  In awk, `!` is negation.  So, this increments `n` for every line that does not match `,,,,,,,,,`.
- `END{print n;}`

  After we have read last line of the last file, print out the value of `n`.